# WPF passing a bool to the view and changing it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

How do i pass a bool from the viewmodel to the view and change the value.
For example in my viewmodel i have created a bool

```
public bool load
{
    get { return m_load; }
    set
    {
        m_load = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(this, o => o.load);
    }
}
```

I then have my `SelectedVm` code

```
public ViewModel SelectedVm
{
    get { return _selectedVm; }
    set
    {        
        _selectedVm = value;
        if (_selectedVm != null && load == true)
        {
            _selectedVm.Load();                   
        }
        Load = false;
        OnPropertyChanged(this, o => o.SelectedVm);               
    }
}
```

In my View the `SelectedVm` is bound twice but only on one of the bindings do i want Load to be called, hence the need to change the bool `load`

So in my view if i have the following

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"  Name="Sample"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleViewModel}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVm, Mode=TwoWay}"     
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Width="500">            
</ListView>
```

How do i change the `bool` load to either true or false 
All of the above are just quick samples, i think this is probably quite simple however i am not that used to `WPF` and am still learning. any advice would be great

Comment: Why do you want to pass a bool from the viewmodel to the view and change the value?

Comment: I have a problem where the method Load() is being called multiple times but it only needs to be called once, in my view SelectedVM is bound twice which means Load() is called twice, but i only want it once, so bool will be set each time SelectedVm is bound. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Your code should call Load() only once, even if you have multiple bindings. what is the problem? – Liel 5 mins ago

Comment: the other binding is a dataContext binding for a new view, i would have thought that meant it was called twice, and it definately is as i have stepped through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you want to get value of Load in View and you want to do it in pure MVVM pattern then create DependencyProperty of bool type in View and Bind it to Load property of VM like

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustom", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(LoadPropertyChangedCallback)));

    public bool Load
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(LoadProperty) ;
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(LoadProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static void LoadPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Do your load stuff here
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetBinding(LoadProperty, new Binding("load"));
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        load = true;
    }
    bool m_load;
    public bool load
    {
        get { return m_load; }
        set
        {
            m_load = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("load");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how you would use this in the view code xaml. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code you published ensures that `Load()` is being called once, even with multiple bindings.

If I understand your real question correctly, you are actually asking for a way to make sure that each `SelectedVM` is calling `Load()` function once, and only once. Right?
if that so, you need to add a bool property to the `ViewModel` class, instead of the main class, that's all.

And then:

```
public ViewModel SelectedVm
{
    get { return _selectedVm; }
    set
    {        
        _selectedVm = value;
        if (_selectedVm != null && _selectedVm.load == true)
        {
           _selectedVm.Load();                   
           _selectedVm.load = false;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(this, o => o.SelectedVm);               
    }
}
```

you can keep your XAML as it is.

Comment: Ok imagine this i have a list of objects each of those objects has another list of sub objects when i run the program the first object is selected and its sub objects are presented to the screen, after a given time the sub objects for that object are refreshed this calls load for the first time (this is fine), then when a new object is selected this should call load only once but for some reason it calls it twice, i have put this down to the bindings calling it more than once

Comment: My guess is that you are creating two `ViewModel` objects, and what you see is a the setter being called on the two objects, that of course contains two diffrent `Load` properties. If you really want our help, you are going to need to post your REAL code.  :)